# Div's margin doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, margin

Well, this is really annoying. I'm struggling with it for 10 minutes now. I have no idea why it is **NOT** working. My problem is, that I am trying to to make a snake game. I've made a *function*, that moves a div using `marginTop` and `marginLeft` properties.

The *function* has a *switch* statement, where the div is mooved. In this statement, everything is ok, div moves. But earlier, in the same *function*, I have an *if* statement, where the div is also supposed to move, under a condition, of course. The point is, that this *if* statement checks if the snake's coords are out of bounds, and if the condition is true, it resets the snake's position. But, apparently, snake's **NOT** mooving at all.

Here's a piece of JS code:

```js
var snake = document.getElementById("snake")

globalDir = "KeyD" // Right.

function getMarg(margin) {
    return parseInt(margin.substring(0, margin.search("px")))
}


function moveSnake() {
    var style = snake.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(snake)

    var snakeX = style.marginLeft
    var snakeY = style.marginTop

    if(getMarg(snakeX) === 500) { // Here, the snake doesn't move.
        snake.style.marginLeft = "0px"
    }

    switch(globalDir) { // Here, the snake mooves.
        case "KeyW":
            snake.style.marginTop = `${getMarg(snakeY) - 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyS":
            snake.style.marginTop = `${getMarg(snakeY) + 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyA":
            snake.style.marginLeft = `${getMarg(snakeX) - 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyD":
            snake.style.marginLeft = `${getMarg(snakeX) + 10}px`

            break
    }
}

/*
* Rest of the code creates a 'looper', that is an interval, which loops the
* function 'moveSnake'. Also, listens for a key press and if any key's
* pressed,'globalDir' variable changes to the pressed key.
*/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, please present a proper [mre] of issues like this, not just the JavaScript code.

Comment: `if(getMarg(snakeX) === 500) { // Here, the snake doesn't move.` - but that condition was actually true, you did verify that? Why are you comparing to _exactly_ 500 pixels here, why is this not a greater than/lesser than comparison?

Comment: @CBroe, yes i did. Technically earlier, I used ```console.log("Test...")``` syntax, and in the console I got 'Test...' printed out, so I am sure, that this condition is once true. I am also sure, that condition like ```getMarg(snakeX) > 499``` or etc. should be fine, and i should get 'Test....' printed out in the console.

Comment: @CBroe here - https://codepen.io/kafajku/pen/GRjjWvG once it goes to the right border, you should get 'It's 500!' printed out in the console.

Comment: You set `snake.style.marginLeft = "0px"` at that point, but your switch statement after that still executes. That would go into the `KeyD` block (assuming you have not pressed any keys yet), and that still uses the old value of `getMarg(snakeX)`, which is still 500, because you did not update `snakeX` in between. `var snakeX = style.marginLeft` only fetches the current value at that time, this does not “live update” `snakeX` later on, when `style.marginLeft` changes,

Comment: @CBroe, oh, yeah that actually works perfect. Thank you for your help. I will add an answer with updated JS code, if somebody is having similar, silly issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**If somebody is having similar, silly issue, here's an updated piece of my JS code, from the question:**

```
var snake = document.getElementById("snake")

globalDir = "KeyD" // Right.

function getMarg(margin) {
    return parseInt(margin.substring(0, margin.search("px")))
}


function moveSnake() {
    var style = snake.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(snake)

    var snakeX = style.marginLeft
    var snakeY = style.marginTop

    if(getMarg(snakeX) === 500) { // Here, the snake doesn't move.
        snake.style.marginLeft = "0px"
    }

    // Update the 'style' and snake's coords
    style = snake.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(snake)

    snakeX = style.marginLeft
    snakeY = style.marginTop

    switch(globalDir) { // Here, the snake mooves.
        case "KeyW":
            snake.style.marginTop = `${getMarg(snakeY) - 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyS":
            snake.style.marginTop = `${getMarg(snakeY) + 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyA":
            snake.style.marginLeft = `${getMarg(snakeX) - 10}px`

            break

        case "KeyD":
            snake.style.marginLeft = `${getMarg(snakeX) + 10}px`

            break
    }
}

/*
* Rest of the code creates a 'looper', that is an interval, which loops the
* function 'moveSnake'. Also, listens for a key press and if any key's
* pressed,'globalDir' variable changes to the pressed key.
*/
```

**Thanks to @CBroe!**